# C++: grammar of move assignment operator

Tags: c++

I have a C++ grammar question related to `X x = X();`, which results in the **move constructor** being invoked using special compilation flags below.

Is the grammar not in a form which one would expect the **move assignment operator** to be called?  There is an rvalue on the right hand side of the equals sign.  Curious if there is some reason behind this or history.

Also curious why commenting out the **move constructor** results in the **copy constructor** is called?

Understood that without the special flags this results in copy elision.  Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct X {
    int x;
    X() : x{0} { cout << "def cons" << endl; }
    X(const X& xx) : x{xx.x} { cout << "copy cons" << endl; }
    X(X&& xx) : x{xx.x} { xx.x = 0; cout << "move cons" << endl; }
    X& operator=(const X& xx) { cout << "assign op" << endl; return *this; }
    X& operator=(X&& xx) { xx.x = 0; cout << "move assign" << endl; return *this; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    X x = X();
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and results:

```
g++ -pedantic -fno-elide-constructors -Wall test145.cc && ./a.out


def cons
move cons
```

Comment: You can only assign something to an object that already exists. The object does not exist yet, it is being constructed. Hence the move constructor. Pretty sure you should also be prepared to say good-bye to the move constructor too, when your compiler gets updated to the current C++ standard.

Comment: Hi, in the output "def cons" is called, so should that object be assigned to?

Comment: this `def` is for the one on R.H.S

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I explicitly added flags to prevent eliding of the constructors so I could see how things would work without optimization.

Comment: Since C++17 it's no longer "copy-elision", it's like if there was no copy here at all. Meaning of "rvalue" changed from "a temporary object" to something like "instructions to create an object whereever needed"

Comment: @asmmo if `def` is RHS, what is the created object the move constructor is being called upon?

Comment: If your class have no move constructor, then copy constructor is called because what else can you do? Especially considering backwards compatibility. More formally, const-lvalue-reference (copy constructor parameter) can bind to both lvalues and rvalues, so it's chosen in the lack of move constructor (which has more specific rvalue-reference as the parameter)

Comment: @notaorb there is a temporary object constructed using the default ctor. the temporary obj then will be used to construct the object on L.H.S. using the move ctor.

Comment: @asmmo thanks thats what I was thinking, but grammer wise isn't it really a move assignment to the temporary value?

Comment: @notaorb It's not an assignment. An assignment looks like `<expr> = <expr>`. `X x = X()` does not look like that, since `X x` is not an expression. Therefore, it isn't an assignment. It's a declaration and it initializes `x` without using any assignment operator.

Comment: @HTNW ok that makes sense, I'll have to read the grammar in the standard some day.  Thanks

Comment: I wonder that you ask for the _grammar of move_. Whether something becomes a move assignment or a copy assignment or a compiler complaint is not subject of the grammar (in your case) but of the semantic analysis. [Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_grammar) is something to describe which stream of characters forms a syntactically correct C++ program. (It's related to formal languages.) E.g. `int main() { int a = "Hello World."; }` is syntactically completely correct (according to the C++ grammar). It's the semantic analysis which will yell on me for my type mis-matching. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object does not exist yet, it is being constructed, therefore requires a constructor.  In this case the move constructor is called because of an rvalue on the RHS.  A temporary object is constructed using the default constructor and this temporary object is then used to construct the object on the LHS using the move constructor.

If the class has no move constructor, then the copy constructor is called for backwards compatibility.  const-lvalue-reference of the copy constructor can bind to both lvalues and rvalues, so the copy constructor is chosen in lack of a move constructor.

The move assignment operator is not called because a move assignment takes form `<expr> = <expr>`.  In the case of this post `X x = X()` is used, which is not an assignment, but is a declaration that initializes x without using assignment.  In this case, it’s a move construction.